# Google Cloud Bigquery: can max row size limit be increased?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I get the following error when iterating through a query result:

`API limit exceeded: Message before conversion exceeds max row limit, limit: 20971520 actual: 33913353`

Limit of 20MB when according to the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas?_ga=2.26008125.-1610886964.1651834125&_gac=1.224891368.1676640550.Cj0KCQiA6LyfBhC3ARIsAG4gkF9RQ1S7C4Qpo-52OYDNvgXqev-JqnwcKPGHBAfAPNecjI5bPIOI54EaAl91EALw_wcB) it seems 100MB.

Can the Maximum Row Size limit in bigquery be increased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you see this error?

The 20MB limit does apply to the "Maximum jobs.query response size".

Per documentation:

> By default, there is no maximum row count for the number of rows of data returned by jobs.query per page of results. However, you are limited to the 20-MB maximum response size. You can alter the number of rows to return by using the maxResults parameter.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#api_request_quotas

Comment: Thanks, so in fact the limit of 20MB does not seem to be configurable.